# SQL Query Multiple Joins to same table

Tags: sql

I have the following table

**Address Table**

```
Code   Company Name    Type   Address Line 1    Address Line 2  City   State  ZIP
ABC01  ABC Company     B      123 Bill To 1     Bill to Apt 2   Newark NJ     12345
ABC01  ABC Company     S      425 Ship To 1     Ship To Line 2  Edison NJ     44445
DEF01  DEF Bill To     B      993 Bill To 1     Bill to Apt 2   Newark NJ     12345
DEF01    
DEF Ship To     S      456 Ship To 1     Ship To Line 2  Edison NJ     44445
```

**Invoice Table**

```
Invoice #   Code    Bill To Name    Ship to Name
12345       ABC01   ABC Company     ABC Company
12346       DEF01   DEF Bill To     DEF Ship To
```

**I need the following results**

```
Invoice #  Code   Bill To Name  Ship To Name   Bill to Address Line 1   Ship to Address Line 1
12345      ABC01  Bill To 1     Ship To 1      123 Bill To 1            425 Ship To 1
12346      DEF01  DEF Bill To   DEF Ship To    993 Bill to 1            456 Ship To 1
```

Basically I need to join the Invoice table to the address table based on the code + Company Name + Type in 2 different joins.

I am stuck with the query and cant figure how to join them together.

Comment: Start with a basic search: [sql how to join tables](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+how+to+join+tables&oq=sql+how+to+join+tables). Do some reading. Then give it a try. If you get stuck come back and show your attempt and what specifically is not working.

Comment: Your query is actually pretty basic.   You will join to the Address table two times.  Just make sure to ALIAS each instance for the respective BillTo vs ShipTo and you should be good.  Aliasing is just listing the table first, then a space and then the alias name you want to refer it to.  It will have its own JOIN ON condition based on the respective BillTo or ShipTo.  If still nothing, EDIT your existing post and show what you HAVE attempted.

Answer (score 0):

for answering your question you can use the following query to get the required result :

```
SELECT invoice.`Invoice #`,invoice.Code,
ba.`Company Name` as "Bill to Name" ,sa.`Company Name` as "Ship to Name" ,
ba.`Address Line 1` as "Bill to Address Line 1", sa.`Address Line 1` 

FROM `invoice` 
 JOIN address as ba on ba.`Company Name` = invoice.`Bill To Name` and ba.Type = 'B'
 JOIN address as sa on sa.`Company Name` = invoice.`Bill To Name` and sa.Type = 'S';
```